# requisição ajax para HTTPS com cordova

Tags: ajax, apache-cordova, https

Como fazer requisição ajax para HTTPS em app feito com cordova?

está retornando o erro "unable to verify the first certificate"

Comment: Você está fazendo essa requisição para o seu próprio servidor local ?

Comment: não.. para meu servidor já hospedado na web.. servidor apache com ssl habilitado e cors tbm.. quando faço a requisição http, funciona normal, quando uso https da o erro, agora descobri isso no retorno {"readyState":4,"responseText":"","status":404,"statusText":"Not Found"} isso como app ja instalado

Comment: então isso é problema com o seu servidor, algum certificado mal instalado ou algo do tipo, tenta elaborar uma melhor pergunta.

Comment: não creio que seja problema no servidor pq requisição feita por navegador funciona normal..

Comment: @MarceloRafael descobri o problema... faltava o certificado intermediário no meu servidor.. obrigado pela ajuda